# Trouble updating a Simple Schema sub document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to update a sub document on an existing collection. I'm getting a MongoDB error message.

```
"MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: articleWords.$ [409]"
```

From my Articles Simple Schema

```
"articleWords.$": {
  type: Object
},
"articleWords.$.wordId": {
  type: String,
  label: 'Word ID'
},
"articleWords.$.word": {
  type: String,
  label: 'Word'
},
```

Update Function

```
function updateArticle(_id,wordArr) {
  _.each(wordArr,function(elem) {
      var ret = Articles.update(
        {'_id': _id},
        { $set: { 'articleWords.$': { 'wordId': elem.wordId, 'word': elem.word } }
      });  
    }); 
  return true;
}
```

As you can see I am passing an array of objects. Is there a better way to do this than _.each ?

**CLARIFICATION**

Thank you to @corvid for the answer. I think I didn't make my question clear enough. There **does** exist an article record, but there is no data added to the **articleWords** attribute. Essentially we are updating a record but insert into the **articleWords** array.

A second attempt, is also not working

```
  _.each(wordArr,function(elem) {
      var ret = Articles.update(
        {'_id': _id},
        { $set: { 'articleWords.$.wordId': elem.wordId, 'articleWords.$.word': elem.word } }
      );  
    });
```

Comment: Intead of _.each you could combine $push and $each operators. Something like { $push: { articleWords: { $each: wordArr } } }

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need your selector to match something within the subdocument. For example,

```
Articles.update({
  '_id': <someid>,
  'words.wordId': <somewordid>
}, {
  $set: {
    'words.$.word': elem.word,
    'words.$.wordId': elem.wordId
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I wasn't clear in the post I think. The subdocument is being created, and added to an existing parent document.

Answer (score 1):

If the array doesn't exist yet then you're going about this in the hardest way possible. You can just set the entire array at one go:

```
var ret = Articles.update(
    {'_id': _id},
    { $set: { articleWords: wordArr }}
);
```

I can see that `wordArr` already has the id and string. This will work as long as it doesn't have more content. If it does then you can just make a second version with the parts you want to keep.

Comment: Thanks Michel. It's not working either... if this is the hardest way, what is the easy way?

Comment: Is `articleWords` defined as an array of objects in your schema? `type: [Object]`? What error message are you getting. This is the easy way, just set the entire array at once as the value of a key.